# component is constantly updated

Tags: reactjs, function

## function called many times though I call it once

## tried useEffect but it didn’t work

`

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react'
import PostService from '../../API/PostService';

import './PlanetRandom.css'

export default function PlanetRandom() {
  const [id, setId] = useState(null)
  const [population, setPopulation] = useState(null)
  const [rotationPeriod, setRotationPeriod] = useState(null)
  const [diameter, setDiameter] = useState(null)
  const [name, setName] = useState(null)

  const postService = new PostService()

  const updatePlanet = ()=>{
    const id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 25 + 2)
    postService
      .getPlanet(id)
      .then((planet) =>{
        setId(id)
        setPopulation(planet.population)
        setDiameter(planet.diameter)
        setRotationPeriod(planet.rotation_period)
        setName(planet.name)
      })
    }
  updatePlanet()


  return (
    
      <div className="random-planet jumbotron rounded">
        <img alt='gay' className="planet-image"
             src={`https://starwars-visualguide.com/assets/img/planets/${id}.jpg`} />
        <div>
          <h4>{name}</h4>
          <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li className="list-group-item">
              <span className="term">Population</span>
              <span>{population}</span>
            </li>
            <li className="list-group-item">
              <span className="term">Rotation Period</span>
              <span>{rotationPeriod}</span>
            </li>
            <li className="list-group-item">
              <span className="term">Diameter</span>
              <span>{diameter}</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>`
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1hi8.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDl4w.png)

## I tried everything but it didn’t work

................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Please add details of what you have tried (more than "everything") and further information about which function is being constantly called/updated

Comment: useEffect should work. Did you pass an empty array to it?

Comment: `useEffect` would be the solution you just need to use it correctly. Please share how you tried to use it so we can see if there's something you missed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You set state in an infinite loop

The way you set updatePlanet will rerun on every rerender this in turn will call sets state and rerender again infinitely until your api stops it.

```
updatePlanet();
```

you can put updatePlanet() in a useEffect

## Solution1: useEffect

useEffect will run when some criteria is met and only when that criteria is met, these are called dependencies you should add some to the square brackets so that it triggers only when they change.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  updatePlanet()
} []) // add some dependencies so it runs after data
```

## Solution 2: set a ref object

This is not a nice implementation but maybe you need this to get the data if you cant get a good use effect dependency

```
const isDataGrabbed = React.useRef(false);

// define get data

// use ref to trigger the grabbing of data
if (!isDataGrabbed.current) {
  updatePlanet();
  isDataGrabbed.current = true;
}
```